What is the expectation of Z which is a function of 2 random variables?
If X,Y are random variables and they follow geometric distribution(p) same for both. Also they are independent r.V's. Define $Z=\frac{X}{Y}$. Find distribution and expectation of $Z$.
I tried solving by assuming $X=k, Y=m$ and $Z=n$ so $X=nY$ but when I did calculations like PMF of $Z=P(Z=n)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty P(X=nm)× P(Y=m)$
But i don't understand how to simplify as Z is not integer or in geometric progression like X and Y ..even if Z was integer then also I got wrong answer I guess.
Can you please guide me in right direction where I understand the essence atleast I'm getting confused a lot

Ohh yess i forgot to mention

Z will be discrete or continuous?

Hint:  $Z$ will take on various rational values. Can you thInk of what these might be? Is $\frac 35$ a possible value for $Z$?   Of course, $X=3,Y=5$ works, but what about $X=6,Y=10$? $X=9,Y=15$ $X=12,Y=20?$ others? Can you write an explicit expression for $P(X=3,Y=5)$ without any gobbledygook that anyone who  has never heard of geometric random variables but has a calculator and is told the value of $p$ can evaluate? Ditto for  $P(X=6,Y=10)$? Can you now write a series for $P(Z=\frac 35)$ nd recognize  ut as a geometric series? Can you lather, rinse, repeat for other values of $3$ and $5$?
